# reshape2 melt not producing all pairs

Tags: r, matrix, distance, reshape, reshape2

I have a 332 x 332 distance matrix with distances between all possible pairs of stations.   I need to transform this matrix into a data.frame with three columns - start.id, end.id, and distance.

I have tried the `melt` function from the `reshape2` package but this is not giving the right result

Here is a snippet of the data

```
mat
    72   79    82     83   116    119    120   127   128    137    143   144   146   147   150   151   152    153    157    160   161
72  NA 6.43 7.458 11.546 3.784 10.252 12.780 4.835 5.230  2.168 10.614 9.806 7.058 6.533 7.117 6.300 6.693  2.595 10.665  3.280 5.338
79  NA   NA 1.406  5.442 2.956  4.317  7.300 1.695 1.525  6.673  4.510 4.616 0.426 0.775 3.460 1.296 0.589  5.257  4.561  4.785 1.571
82  NA   NA    NA  5.656 4.101  4.213  7.152 2.840 2.554  6.410  4.601 3.767 1.447 1.796 2.694 1.400 1.610  5.947  4.652  5.452 2.495
83  NA   NA    NA     NA 8.447  1.736  2.170 7.347 6.782 11.050  1.958 1.888 5.005 5.192 6.826 5.599 5.039 10.175  2.426  9.226 6.723
116 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA  7.156  9.684 1.739 2.134  4.741  7.860 6.710 3.359 3.779 4.626 3.204 3.939  3.327  7.911  3.702 2.242
119 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA  2.970 6.158 5.593  9.861  2.397 0.699 4.209 4.396 5.637 4.410 4.243  8.986  2.403  8.037 5.534
120 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA 8.418 7.853 12.101  3.409 2.959 6.477 6.664 6.962 6.670 6.511 11.315  3.899 10.274 7.794
127 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA 1.411  5.137  6.358 5.734 2.201 2.277 3.903 2.176 2.437  3.721  6.409  4.095 1.519
128 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA  5.131  5.629 4.973 1.545 1.884 3.187 1.415 1.708  3.715  5.680  4.089 0.803
137 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA 12.152 8.855 7.651 8.071 5.996 5.377 8.231  1.744 12.203  1.821 4.729
143 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA 1.956 3.707 3.894 5.632 4.405 3.741  8.981  0.489  8.032 5.529
144 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA 3.902 4.089 4.937 3.710 3.936  8.286  2.096  7.337 4.834
146 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA 0.348 3.695 1.695 0.508  5.307  4.480  5.681 1.922
147 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA 4.104 2.092 0.803  5.932  4.378  6.306 2.371
150 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 1.818 3.474  4.786  5.697  3.745 1.793
151 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 1.792  4.554  5.008  3.682 1.102
152 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  6.111  3.971  5.178 1.964
153 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA  8.798  0.684 3.513
157 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA  8.467 5.964
160 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA 3.153
161 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
164 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
167 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
168 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
173 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
174 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
195 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
212 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
216 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
217 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
218 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
223 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
224 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
225 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
228 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
229 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
232 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
233 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
236 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
237 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
238 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
239 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
241 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
242 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
243 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
244 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
245 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
247 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
248 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
249 NA   NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA    NA
       164    167   168    173   174   195    212    216    217    218   223   224   225    228   229    232    233   236   237   238
72   2.978  3.446 4.112  1.401 5.321 7.529  3.404 10.426 10.561 10.305 4.915 7.890 3.839  2.611 5.804  9.826 10.006 5.368 5.180 4.715
79   6.082  4.951 3.242  5.981 4.483 1.425  3.270  4.322  4.457  4.201 3.054 1.786 3.031  5.689 1.885  3.722  3.902 2.609 3.018 2.657
82   6.472  6.024 3.932  6.671 4.572 1.289  4.415  4.413  4.003  4.326 3.744 0.734 4.176  5.950 2.055  3.813  3.993 2.972 3.039 3.802
83   9.689  9.241 8.160 10.899 8.090 5.151  8.634  2.960  3.386  1.208 7.972 5.160 8.395  9.924 6.283  2.360  1.589 6.746 6.813 8.021
116  4.921  3.868 1.314  3.660 3.600 4.775  0.791  7.672  6.946  7.551 1.819 5.136 0.743  4.554 2.708  7.072  7.252 3.086 2.745 1.619
119  8.500  8.052 6.971  9.710 6.901 4.355  7.793  2.164  2.197  1.815 6.783 4.364 7.554  8.735 5.094  1.564  1.744 5.557 5.624 7.180
120 10.740 10.292 9.231 11.970 8.840 6.623 10.053  4.432  4.457  2.676 9.043 6.632 9.814 11.439 7.354  3.832  3.057 7.668 7.735 9.440
127  5.317  4.261 1.706  4.445 3.993 3.273  1.604  6.170  6.305  6.049 1.518 3.634 1.365  4.950 1.985  5.570  5.750 2.363 2.444 0.991
128  5.311  4.255 1.700  4.439 3.987 2.544  2.522  5.441  5.209  5.320 1.512 2.905 2.283  4.944 1.269  4.841  5.021 1.993 2.349 1.909
137  1.448  1.987 5.308  1.514 4.296 9.067  5.083 11.964  9.091  9.414 4.639 9.428 5.035  1.081 4.693 11.364 11.544 4.530 4.425 5.911
143  8.495  8.047 6.966  9.705 6.896 3.853  7.336  1.248  1.312  0.903 6.778 3.862 7.097  8.730 5.089  1.032  1.212 5.552 5.619 6.723
144  7.800  7.352 6.271  9.010 6.201 4.048  7.093  1.857  1.497  1.565 6.083 4.057 6.854  8.035 4.394  1.257  1.437 4.857 4.924 6.480
146  6.903  5.847 3.292  6.031 4.882 1.344  3.790  4.241  4.376  4.120 3.104 1.705 3.551  6.536 2.284  3.641  3.821 3.008 3.417 3.177
147  7.528  6.472 3.917  6.656 6.204 0.954  3.815  4.139  4.274  4.018 3.729 1.315 3.576  7.161 2.685  3.539  3.719 3.409 4.655 3.202
150  4.211  3.763 3.355  5.803 2.311 3.889  4.076  5.458  4.774  5.097 3.167 3.334 3.834  4.910 1.374  4.858  5.038 1.565 1.633 3.929
151  4.888  3.848 2.539  5.278 3.289 2.052  3.361  4.769  4.085  4.408 2.351 2.235 3.122  4.586 0.691  4.169  4.349 1.415 1.824 2.748
152  6.475  5.344 4.096  6.835 4.876 0.835  3.994  3.732  3.867  3.611 3.908 1.196 3.755  7.340 2.278  3.132  3.312 3.002 3.411 3.381
153  1.595  0.850 3.017  1.653 3.159 5.653  4.056  8.559  7.875  8.198 3.295 6.049 4.008  1.228 3.477  7.959  8.139 3.314 3.288 4.884
157  8.930  8.482 7.401 10.140 7.331 4.288  7.771  1.336  1.654  0.980 7.213 4.297 7.532  9.165 5.524  1.467  0.972 5.987 6.054 7.158
160  1.721  0.477 2.468  2.056 2.274 5.293  3.714  8.199  7.515  7.838 2.935 5.689 3.666  1.354 3.117  7.599  7.779 2.954 2.604 4.542
161  4.716  3.379 1.520  4.259 3.117 2.744  2.187  5.688  5.004  5.327 1.332 3.154 2.094  4.117 0.766  5.088  5.268 1.183 1.545 1.918
164     NA  1.280 3.582  1.578 3.447 6.407  4.828  9.313  8.629  8.952 4.049 8.390 4.780  0.698 4.231  8.713  8.893 4.068 3.718 5.656
167     NA     NA 2.764  2.039 2.570 5.589  4.004  8.495  7.811  8.134 3.231 5.985 3.956  1.337 3.413  7.895  8.075 3.250 2.900 4.832
168     NA     NA    NA  3.357 2.286 4.184  2.174  7.090  6.406  6.729 1.587 4.580 2.126  3.280 2.008  6.490  6.670 1.845 1.657 2.517
173     NA     NA    NA     NA 3.984 7.547  3.563 10.444  8.592  8.915 3.773 7.908 3.515  1.339 4.194  9.844 10.024 4.031 3.843 4.391
174     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA 4.963  3.386  6.871  6.187  6.510 2.605 6.042 3.338  2.747 2.345  6.271  6.451 1.626 1.394 3.730
195     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA  4.797  4.515  4.650  4.394 4.711 0.901 4.558  8.143 3.061  3.915  4.095 3.785 4.267 4.184
212     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA  7.599  6.873  7.478 1.746 5.063 0.670  4.481 2.635  6.999  7.179 3.013 2.672 1.546
216     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA  0.318  2.122 6.556 4.473 7.327  8.508 4.867  1.643  1.823 5.330 5.397 6.953
217     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA  1.933 6.367 4.284 7.138  8.319 4.678  1.454  1.634 5.141 5.208 6.764
218     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 6.669 4.055 7.290  8.621 4.980  1.255  0.840 5.443 5.510 6.916
223     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA 4.562 0.866  4.136 1.945  6.498  6.678 1.852 1.630 1.127
224     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA 4.318  7.903 2.802  3.675  3.855 3.719 3.786 3.944
225     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA  4.720 2.493  6.567  6.747 2.871 2.530 1.114
228     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA 4.322  9.316  9.496 3.862 3.630 5.747
229     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA  4.779  4.959 1.002 1.411 2.308
232     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA  0.652 4.992 5.059 6.163
233     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA 5.581 5.648 6.752
236     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA 0.674 2.971
237     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA 2.596
238     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
239     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
241     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
242     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
243     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
244     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
245     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
247     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
248     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
249     NA     NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
       239    241    242    243    244    245   247   248   249
72  10.949 11.610 10.418 10.941 11.611 10.754 4.191 6.089 6.269
79   4.845  5.506  5.228  4.837  5.748  4.650 2.449 0.934 0.784
82   4.697  5.358  4.379  4.995  5.572  4.502 3.594 2.079 1.929
83   1.337  1.042  2.022  0.625  2.209  1.496 7.940 5.990 5.840
116  7.640  8.301  7.322  7.938  8.515  7.445 1.095 3.342 3.522
119  1.043  1.176  0.648  1.341  1.373  0.538 6.751 5.194 5.044
120  2.400  1.684  2.406  1.832  1.414  2.205 9.011 7.462 7.312
127  6.693  7.354  6.346  6.685  7.596  6.498 0.898 1.816 1.996
128  5.903  6.564  5.585  6.201  6.778  5.708 1.480 1.696 1.617
137  9.785 10.446  9.467 10.083 11.657  9.590 5.387 7.634 7.814
143  2.173  2.409  2.568  1.926  3.076  1.978 6.630 4.692 4.542
144  0.929  1.590  0.611  1.227  1.804  0.734 6.051 4.887 4.737
146  4.764  5.425  5.147  4.756  5.667  4.569 3.084 0.984 0.834
147  4.662  5.323  5.045  4.654  5.565  4.467 3.109 1.756 1.606
150  5.468  6.129  5.150  5.766  5.796  5.273 3.391 3.846 3.767
151  4.779  5.440  4.461  5.077  5.654  4.584 2.319 2.153 2.003
152  4.255  4.916  4.638  4.247  5.158  4.060 3.288 1.349 1.199
153  8.569  9.230  8.251  8.867 10.199  8.374 4.360 6.607 6.787
157  2.317  2.336  3.003  1.853  3.220  2.122 7.065 5.127 4.977
160  8.209  8.870  7.891  8.507  9.084  8.014 4.018 5.535 5.219
161  5.698  6.359  5.380  5.996  6.573  5.503 1.380 2.140 2.061
164  9.323  9.984  9.005  9.621 10.487  9.128 5.132 7.379 7.559
167  8.505  9.166  8.187  8.803  9.809  8.310 4.308 6.555 6.735
168  7.100  7.761  6.782  7.398  7.975  6.905 1.979 4.187 4.367
173  9.286  9.947  8.968  9.584 10.161  9.091 3.867 6.114 6.294
174  6.881  7.542  6.563  7.179  7.756  6.686 3.192 5.205 4.889
195  5.038  5.699  5.421  5.030  5.941  4.843 4.091 2.132 1.982
212  7.567  8.228  7.249  7.865  8.442  7.372 1.022 3.269 3.449
216  2.656  3.317  2.338  2.954  3.531  2.461 6.524 5.303 5.153
217  2.467  3.128  2.149  2.765  3.342  2.272 6.335 5.114 4.964
218  1.348  2.009  1.975  1.340  2.251  1.153 6.823 4.885 4.735
223  6.877  7.538  6.559  7.175  7.752  6.682 0.589 2.768 2.948
224  4.798  5.459  5.181  4.790  5.701  4.603 3.851 1.892 1.742
225  7.690  8.351  7.107  7.682  8.300  7.495 0.880 2.837 3.017
228  9.926 10.587  9.608 10.224 10.254  9.731 5.223 7.470 7.650
229  5.389  6.050  5.071  5.687  6.264  5.194 1.770 2.563 2.484
232  1.613  2.274  2.008  1.605  2.516  1.418 6.070 4.132 3.982
233  1.968  2.137  2.597  1.654  2.871  1.773 6.659 4.721 4.571
236  5.862  6.523  5.544  6.160  6.538  5.667 2.433 4.176 3.769
237  5.917  6.578  5.599  6.215  6.792  5.722 2.058 3.801 3.394
238  6.997  7.658  6.741  6.989  7.900  6.802 0.454 2.144 2.324
239     NA  1.363  1.555  0.656  1.831  0.733 6.969 5.031 4.881
241     NA     NA  1.727  0.550  1.914  0.875 7.319 5.778 5.628
242     NA     NA     NA  1.812  1.192  0.920 6.663 5.472 5.322
243     NA     NA     NA     NA  2.059  0.888 7.332 5.492 5.342
244     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA  1.612 8.418 6.869 6.719
245     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 6.786 5.245 5.095
247     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA 2.341 2.521
248     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA 0.669
249     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    NA    NA    NA
```

```
test = melt(dist_mat)
   No id variables; using all as measure variables
   head(test)
     variable value
   1       72    NA
   2       72    NA
   3       72    NA
   4       72    NA
   5       72    NA
   6       72    NA
```

How can I obtain all possible pairs and values associated with them  ?

```
dput(mat)
structure(list(`72` = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), `79` = c(6.43, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `82` = c(7.458, 1.406, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `83` = c(11.546, 5.442, 5.656, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), `116` = c(3.784, 2.956, 4.101, 8.447, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), `119` = c(10.252, 4.317, 4.213, 1.736, 7.156, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `120` = c(12.78, 7.3, 7.152, 2.17, 9.684, 2.97, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `127` = c(4.835, 1.695, 2.84, 7.347, 1.739, 6.158, 
8.418, NA, NA, NA), `128` = c(5.23, 1.525, 2.554, 6.782, 2.134, 
5.593, 7.853, 1.411, NA, NA), `137` = c(2.168, 6.673, 6.41, 11.05, 
4.741, 9.861, 12.101, 5.137, 5.131, NA)), .Names = c("72", "79", 
"82", "83", "116", "119", "120", "127", "128", "137"), row.names = c("72", 
"79", "82", "83", "116", "119", "120", "127", "128", "137"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what tag would that be?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you not specifying an id-variable. You can create one by transforming the row names into a variable and then `melt`:

```
mat$rn <- row.names(mat)
m1 <- melt(mat, id.vars = "rn")
```

which gives:

```
> head(m1, 15)
    rn variable value
1   72       72    NA
2   79       72    NA
3   82       72    NA
4   83       72    NA
5  116       72    NA
6  119       72    NA
7  120       72    NA
8  127       72    NA
9  128       72    NA
10 137       72    NA
11  72       79  6.43
12  79       79    NA
13  82       79    NA
14  83       79    NA
15 116       79    NA
```

---

However, you did not supply a matrix, but a dataframe in your `dput`. When you apply the `melt` function to a matrix without specifying an id variable, it works as expected:

```
m <- as.matrix(mat)
m2 <- melt(m)
```

which gives:

```
> head(m2,15)
   Var1 Var2 value
1    72   72    NA
2    79   72    NA
3    82   72    NA
4    83   72    NA
5   116   72    NA
6   119   72    NA
7   120   72    NA
8   127   72    NA
9   128   72    NA
10  137   72    NA
11   72   79  6.43
12   79   79    NA
13   82   79    NA
14   83   79    NA
15  116   79    NA
```

Comment: Thanks Jaap, I have added a reproducible sample of the same data.  If you use `melt` on it though, it does not work, any idea why ?

Comment: @iskandarblue The data you posted is hard to read because you cut the data in parts and pasted them underneath each other. It is much better to include the output of `dput(mat)` to your question. That makes it pretty easy for me to reproduce your distance matrix.

Comment: The data is too large to include in a question (it is a 332 x 332 matrix), that is why I cut it

Comment: @iskandarblue You could try `dput(mat[1:10,1:10])`

Comment: I added `dput(mat[1:10, 1:10])`

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you? What's wrong with the output? I tested @Jaaps code on the data you provided, and it gives me a three-column dataframe with row-names,column-names and values.

Comment: @Heroka I think that the problem is that @iskandarblue thought he was applying the `melt` function to a matrix, while in fact he was applying it to a dataframe